# function to see if element has been "dragged"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

Okay, i want to use [Jquery sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/#default) to sort a list.

When a list item is moved up or down, I want to save the current ordering to the database using jquery/ajax.

But how do i check if an item has been moved or not? Is there a function that can check that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several events: http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/.
Just add a listener 'stop' event to http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#event-stop, and define a callback for that.

```
$( ".selector" ).sortable({
  stop: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

Comment: So when I drag an item up or down and release it this function will be called?

Comment: yes, please make a fiddle with your code. Instead of $( ".selector" ) you need to add yours...

Comment: Amazing, it works! Thanks very much mate ;) (Sorry for late response! Was very busy :) )

Comment: You've welcome. Each jQueryUI component have events already setup.